# Create different qaulities for my manifest with only mp4box

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4box

I asked a question on slack on why the quality and bitrate of my dash video wasn't changing and I got this response: `You only have one quality in your manifest. there is no way for the player to choose a different one`

So how can I create different "qualities"?

I have a mp4box command like:

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live -bs-switching multi -url-template whatever.mp4#trackID=1:id=vid0:role=vid0 whatever.mp4#trackID=2:id=aud0:role=aud0 -out whatever.mpd
```

Would it be possible to create different "qualities" with only mp4box or would I have to create the same video with different resolutions with something like ffmpeg and then feed them into the inputs to the command above?

Comment: mp4box is not a transcoder, so you'll have to use one, like ffmpeg.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: Used to be true, but since v0.9 MP4Box can also transcode. See https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/mp4box-filters for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPAC contributor here. Since v0.9, GPAC has introduced a new architecture that allows to transcode by leveraging FFmpeg.

Example (forced intra period of 2 seconds):

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live -out session.mpd source.mp4:@@enc:c=avc:fintra=2
```

Edit: since 2020/09/29 multi-encoding is possible

```
MP4Box -fgraph -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live source.mp4:@ffsws:osize=160x120@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=100k:#Representation=1@@ffsws:osize=320x240@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=200k:#Representation=2
```

Please let us know if you have any questions!

Comment: So what would be an example of giving the inputs certain resolutions, or is my understanding a bit off? Also what does an intra period do?

Comment: At the moment MP4Box can only transcode to one resolution: ```MP4Box --fgraph -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live -out session.mpd ?.\counter_video_180.mp4:@@ffsws:osize=160x120@@enc:c=avc:fintra=2```. We could change that if people file some feature requests.

Comment: The recommended solution is to use the new 'gpac' executable (see https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/dash_low_latency for proper display): ```gpac --profile=dashavc264.live --segdur=1 
 #specify the source
 -i av://:FID=1

 #specify rescalers and encoders for 1080p and 720p
 ffsws:osize=1920x1080:SID=1 @ enc:c=avc:fintra=1:FID=EV1:b=6m
 ffsws:osize=1280x720:SID=1 @ enc:c=avc:fintra=1:FID=EV2:b=3m

 #specify AAC encoding 
 enc:ffc=aac:SID=1:FID=EA:b=128k

 #specify output in DASH, using only sources from video and audio encoders 
 -o live.mpd:gpac:SID=EV1,EV2,EA```

Comment: I tried this, but however nothing happened: ```gpac --profile=dashavc264.live --segdur=1  -i testfile.mp4:FID=1 ffsws:osize=1920x1080:SID=1 @ enc:c=avc:fintra=1:FID=EV1:b=6m   ffsws:osize=1280x720:SID=1 @ enc:c=avc:fintra=1:FID=EV2:b=3m    enc:ffc=aac:SID=1:FID=EA:b=128k   -o output.mpd:gpac:SID=EV1,EV2,EA``` I believe I messed up, but I don't know where. I wasn't sure what I was supposed to put in, especially for the input file. Sorry lol I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: I did some debugging and I got this: `sh: 1: gpac: not foundint(127) array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "sh: 1: gpac: not found" }`

Comment: Ok, you need to install a recent gpac distribution. We provide installers on our website http://gpac.io

Comment: We have added the feature in MP4Box (multi quality encoding): ```MP4Box -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live source.mp4:@ffsws:osize=160x120@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=100k:#Representation=1@@ffsws:osize=320x240@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=200k:#Representation=2```

Comment: ```MP4Box -dash 2000 -profile dashavc264:live test.mp4#video:@ffsws:osize=160x120@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=100k:#Representation=1@@ffsws:osize=1920x1080@enc:c=avc:fintra=2:b=200k:#Representation=2  ".$filentmpname."#audio -out test.mpd``` <- I used this, however there was only one video representation with the resolution set to the source of the video (test.mp4) in the manifest file. Did I do something wrong? Also I really appreciate how you've been helping.

Comment: Should I continue looking at the gpac option you provided? Before, I tried using these commands (im on ubuntu) `sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config g++ git scons cmake yasm` and `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-dev libpng-dev libmad0-dev libfa....` but it still returned the same error.

Comment: These comments are not appropriate for such support. I am the only dev here and I don't get notifications either. Would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues?